# How can I decode the http encrypted cookie in Jmeter

Tags: cookies, jmeter

I am now using Jmeter to prepare a test plan for my web. The rough flow of the script is that I can check my profile after login. I tried to run my recorded script, and found that the cookie is encoded in http format which I don't want it to be.

Therefore, I would like to ask is there anyway so that I can have a not encrypted cookie value?

[I applied a cookie manager in the script.
The value of the cookie now is something like "%22mh8eIAH8rfsZsM3r%22".
The value that I want is something like "mh8eIAH8rfsZsM3r"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%22` means `"` which is [percent-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), if you want to decode it back - take a look at [__urldecode()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urldecode) function:

[image]

In general you should not be recording any cookies, you need to add a [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) and JMeter will automatically extract incoming cookies from [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) response header and add them to the next request as [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) header if domain and path match the ones in the cookie, it's not expired, etc

If you need to access the cookie value as a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) the easiest way is adding the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
CookieManager.save.cookies=true
```

and upon JMeter restart you will be able to use the cookie value as `${COOKIE_your-cookie-name-here}`

More information: [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide)